# Pass values between Forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I have several forms(I'm not using formwizard)
I want to take decisions based in the value of previous form.
For instance: 
- disable a form2.field the if form1.field has a specific value
- Transfer a value from form1 to form2
I'd like to put all the logic in the forms.

I was trying to get the value in the save in the session from the form, I couldn't

```
class form1(forms.ModelForm):
...

class form2(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
       ms = kwargs.pop('fieldform1',None)
       if ms == 'value':
          self.fields['fieldform1'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update **get_form_kwargs** method in you view to pass **form1 field values**

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    """Returns the keyword arguments for instantiating the form."""
    kwargs = super(YourViewName, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs['fieldform1'] = 'fieldform1value'
    return kwargs
```

Ref [django views](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py?_e_pi_=7%2CPAGE_ID10%2C2137608745)

Comment: Thank you so much @Ashish. Brief and Clear